# Check if a renderObject or an Element is currently visible

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to find the number of widget currently visible by the user on flutter Android / iOS using RenderObject or Element.

To do it, I found a way similar way what we can found on JS Web : document.getElementsBy but on flutter mobile.

This work well except for ListView / SliverList. Theses widgets are optimised to only display the exact number of items which fit the screen. By default ListView use cacheExtent to display a bit more items into a kind of prebuild mode.

I would like to know how i can fix the code bellow to filter Widget which are inside this prebuild cacheExtent mode. I would like to get only the visible items.

I don't want to use VisibilityDetector because it require to wrap every widget with it and do black magic to achieve more complexe task.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

extension DomBuildContextExtension on BuildContext {
  /// Return a List<T> which contain all widget of type T visible under the current context
  /// Do not call this during build. See flutter doc.
  List<T> getElementsByType<T>() {
    final List<T> results = <T>[];

    void parser(Element element) {
      if (element.widget is T) {
        results.add(element.widget as T);
      } else {
        element.visitChildElements(parser);
      }
    }

    visitChildElements(parser);
    return results;
  }
}
```

Comment: so it seems you have to filter out those render boxes that are outside the scrolling viewport, you can get the viewport dimensions with static `Scrollable.of` method which returns `ScrollableState`

Comment: Will dig that, ty @pskink :)

Comment: Scrollable.of(context) return null. This getElementsByType is not called inside the build but outside.

Comment: so what `BuildContext` are you using to call it?

Comment: Likely a BuildContext inside a call back, inside initState.

I really build a system similar to the web dom getElementsById but for mobile :)